# RuntimeError: ffi_prep_cif failed

Tags: ctypes, ffi

I am working on a project where I have to use ctypes to call a few C functions from a C file in a Python script. I have created a shared object from the C file and used it inside my Python script.

I have defined the C struct in ctypes, but I am getting a `RuntimeError` while running my Python script. The error is:

> `ffi_prep_cif failed`

I have included ffi.h header in my C file and again created the shared object, but I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

The code which I have written for the wrapper in Python is as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib_fib = ctypes.CDLL('./lib6.so')

    class model_t(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields__ = [('weight', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),
                     ('threshold', ctypes.c_float)]

    data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
    f1 = 2.5
    l = len(data)
    m = model_t()
    m.weight = (ctypes.c_float * l)(*data)
    m.threshold = (ctypes.c_float * 1)(l)

    chr_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
    c = 'abcd'
    l1 = len(c)
    chr_p = (ctypes.c_char * l1)(*c)

    out = lib_fib.new_classify(m, chr_p)
    print out`
```

I am trying to replace Python function called `self.abc_prob()` with C `new_classify()`. This is a part of my C function, which I want to call using ctypes:

```
extern double 
new_classify(model_t *model_ptr, char *s) 
{
    char bigram[3];         /* Used only when debugging */

    float *model_weights = model_ptr->weights;
    float threshold = model_ptr->threshold;

    /* ... */
```

Comment: Why does your C library need a libffi header?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed ideally. I was just trying different methods.The same runtime error was coming when I din't use ffi.h. I used gcc-shared -Wl,-soname,lib6 -o lib6.so -fPIC adr.c (lib6 is my shared object name) I have added my python wrapper as well as the c function which I am trying to call using ctypes to the main question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: In `model_t`, the attribute name should be `_fields_`, not `_fields__`. Fixing that will expose a type error in assigning `m.threshold`. It should be a single float value, not an array. The statement `chr_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` is doing nothing and should be removed. `chr_p = (ctypes.c_char * l1)(*c)` is wrong because it should be a null-terminated string. Use `ctypes.c_char_p(c)` if the string is a constant (but then your C code should declare it `const`)  and `ctypes.create_string_buffer(c)` otherwise. The struct should be passed by reference, e.g. `ctypes.byref(m)`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun. That worked.

Comment: @ErykSun Want to post this as an answer? I had the same problem with typoing `_fields_`